# Looking for String.matchAll alternative in js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to use `matchAll` like this:

```
const regexp = /t(e)(st(\d?))/g;
const str = 'test1test2';
const array = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
```

but I got error:

> matchall is not function or its return value is not iterable

Maybe my browser or js version not supported.
but which alternative i have for `matchAll` for lower versions?

tnx

Comment: Doesn’t the code provided in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#regexp.exec_and_matchall) help?

Comment: Use `match` with the `/g` flag.

Comment: Actually its not the same const array = [...str.matchAll(regexp)]; return array of 2 arrays  and return array of 2 values, i looking for the first one results

Comment: The error message says `matchall` not `matchAll`. Did you copy the error wrong, or did you mistype the function name in the code?

Comment: I think any browser that supports `...` should also have `matchAll`.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure what makes you say this. [`...`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility) is older than [`matchAll`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#browser_compatibility).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Browsers that support ES6 have been getting updated, and they all have `matchAll` now. So unless he needs to support old versions of "modern" browsers, it shouldn't be an issue

Comment: there is no error [
    [
        "test1",
        "e",
        "st1",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "test2",
        "e",
        "st2",
        "2"
    ]
]